# Нахождение MD5 файлов в папке WinApi

Tags: java

Есть функция для нахождения md5 одного конкретного файла, как мне ее преобразовать, чтобы она находила md5 для всех файлов в папке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас метка `c++`. Отлично. Убедитесь, что ваш компилятор поддерживает C++17.

Выделите свою функцию в таки функцию. Пусть, например, это

```
void md5forFile(const char * filename);
```

После этого, чтоб найти все-все-все файлы, скажем, в `C:\Users` с подкаталогами, просто пишете

```
for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\Users"))
    if (p.is_regular_file())
        md5forFile(p.path().string().c_str());
```

Всё.

Для широких символов - примерно так:

```
void md5forFile(const wchar_t* w)
{
    wcout << w << endl;
}

int main()
{

    for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("C:\\Users"))
        if (p.is_regular_file())
            md5forFile(p.path().wstring().c_str());
}
```

Comment: Ну, а если вы работаете с широкими символами, то см. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Лучше функцию взятия имен файлов брать сразу широкими символами, потому что даже файл на русском и на немецком языках - перевод сразу один из уйдет в крякозябры. Не лучшая идея ANSI в Widestring переводить.